# The the_post_thumbnail without srcset?

Tags: theme-development, themes, post-thumbnails, images

The WordPress 4.4 adds multiple image sizes with `srcset` when using `the_post_thumbnail` function. Is it possible to get only one image size without srcset ?

I understand that it is possible to add a filter to disable `srcset` from all images, but I want to disable the `srcset` only when calling a specific thumbnail size (for example only when calling full image size).

Answer (score 14):

> I want to disable the srcset only when calling a specific thumbnail
>   size (for example only when calling full image size).

Here are two ideas (if I understand you correctly):

### Approach #1

Let's check the size from the `post_thumbnail_size` filter. If it matches a corresponding size (e.g. `full`) then we make sure the `$image_meta` is empty, with the `wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta` filter. That way we can bail out early from the `wp_calculate_image_srcset()` function (earlier than using the `max_srcset_image_width` or `wp_calculate_image_srcset` filters to disable it):

```
/**
 * Remove the srcset attribute from post thumbnails 
 * that are called with the 'full' size string: the_post_thumbnail( 'full' )
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214071/26350
 */
 add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_size', function( $size )
 {
     if( is_string( $size ) && 'full' === $size )
         add_filter( 
             'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta',  
              '__return_null_and_remove_current_filter' 
         );   
    return $size;
 } );

// Would be handy, in this example, to have this as a core function ;-)
function __return_null_and_remove_current_filter ( $var )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return null;
}
```

If we have:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
```

then the generated `<img>` tag will not contain the `srcset` attribute.

For the case:

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

we could match the `'post-thumbnail'` size string.

### Approach #2

We could also add/remove the filter manually with:

```
// Add a filter to remove srcset attribute from generated <img> tag
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta', '__return_null' );

// Display post thumbnail
the_post_thumbnail();

// Remove that filter again
remove_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta', '__return_null' );
```

Comment: you probably need to also remove the `wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta` filter when the function ends

Comment: I added the approach where we add/remove the filter callback manually. I use the instance counting in the other approach to run it only once for each the_post_thumbnail() call @MarkKaplun

Comment: I simplified the code snippet, thanks for letting me think about this again ;-) @MarkKaplun

Comment: :) I just found a productive way to show my dislike to anonymous functions in filters :)

Comment: It would be handy to have core functions like `__return_null_and_remove_current_filter` ;-) Let me adjust the answer to promote it here ;-)  @MarkKaplun

Comment: or there should be a "run one time" parameter to `add_filter`. This pattern is really common.

Comment: yes, that would be even better or just pass the number of allowed runs or allow extra callbacks for extended runtime logic  @MarkKaplun

Answer (score 1):

No filters are necessary. The most simple solution is below:

```
// exclude any attribute you want to keep from the list
// choose any defined image size, ie. large, medium, etc
echo preg_replace( '/(width|height|srcset|sizes)="[^"]*"/', '', get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'large') );
```

Comment: This is perfect if you just want to disable the `srcset` in a single location in your theme. But if you want to get rid of it everywhere, using the filter seems a neater solution.